# Append multiple tags on same level if a specific tag is already there

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I changed now multiple times my xsl, but I didn't find the right way. Now here is what I want:

I try to find now all missing Pages, which got no description. If it's missing, I want to add a description for that page, if it exist, I want to modify the Description. The String for pageX to pageXDescription is always the same.

Here is my short example xml:

```
 <BOOK>
    <PAGE NAME='page1' VALUE='coolText'/>
    <PAGE NAME='Description1' VALUE='coolDescription'/>
    <PAGE NAME='page2' VALUE='moreText'/>
    <PAGE NAME='page3' VALUE='aLotMoreText'/>
    <PAGE NAME='Description3' VALUE='aLotMoreDescriptions'/>
  </BOOK>
```

I tried it with something like that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- define output settings and header -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" media-type="string" encoding="ISO-8859-1" doctype-system="deftable.dtd"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="BOOK[PAGE/@NAME='page1']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="create_missing_description_pages">
                <xsl:with-param name="page" select="'page1'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="description" select="'Description1'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="new_description" select="'newContent'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="BOOK[PAGE/@NAME='page2']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="create_missing_description_pages">
                <xsl:with-param name="page" select="'page2'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="description" select="'Description2'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="new_description" select="'newContent'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="BOOK[PAGE/@NAME='page3']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="create_missing_description_pages">
                <xsl:with-param name="page" select="'page3'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="description" select="'Description3'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="new_description" select="'newContent'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Function to generate missing XML Tags -->
    <xsl:template name="create_missing_description_pages">
        <xsl:param name="page"/>
        <xsl:param name="description"/>
        <xsl:param name="new_description"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|VARIABLE[@NAME=$page]/preceding-sibling::node()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="VARIABLE[@NAME=$page]"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(VARIABLE/@NAME=$description)">
            <xsl:element name="PAGE">
                <xsl:attribute name="NAME"><xsl:value-of select="$description"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="VALUE"><xsl:value-of select="$new_description"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="VARIABLE[@NAME=$page]/following-sibling::node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="BOOK/PAGE">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@NAME='Description1'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="NAME"><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">newContent</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@NAME='Description2'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="NAME"><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">newContent</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@NAME='page3Description'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="NAME"><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">newContent</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- other child items will just be copied -->
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That is what I'm expecting in all cases, if all Descriptions are missing, or if all Descriptions are available:

```
  <BOOK>
    <PAGE NAME='page1' VALUE='coolText'/>
    <PAGE NAME='Description1' VALUE='newContent'/>
    <PAGE NAME='page2' VALUE='moreText'/>
    <PAGE NAME='Description2' VALUE='newContent'/>
    <PAGE NAME='page3' VALUE='aLotMoreText'/>
    <PAGE NAME='Description3' VALUE='newContent'/>
  </BOOK>
```

If there is no page3, then I want also no page Description.

I hope so, that it's understandable.

Thanks a lot for a hint, where my logical failure is and how to fix it.

Best regards
Björn

Comment: Are `page1` and `page1Description` and so on the real names in your XML input, i.e. is there a scheme to that naming the XSLT could match on?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for response. Yes, they are in the end the real names, but I generated this example only to show my problem. The real xml is much more complicated. This is not a good XML structure, but I can't change the input structure. I hope that I could answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you make this simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PAGE">
    <xsl:variable name="pagenum" select="xs:integer(substring-after(@NAME, 'page'))" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <PAGE NAME='Description{$pagenum}'>
        <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$pagenum=1">newContent1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$pagenum=2">newContent2</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$pagenum=3">newContent3</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
     </PAGE>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PAGE[starts-with(@NAME, 'Description')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry for the bad example. The identifier page1 and so on, is not available in description or value. That was only an example for content. I'll edit my question. Best regards Björn

Comment: Hi Michael, I changed it now to a closer example then before. The number of page and description are really the same, but not the content of the value. Thanks a lot. Best regards Björn

Comment: @Björn Where are the description values coming from? Can they be calculated or do you have an array from which they can be looked up by the page name or number?

Comment: Hi Michael, in the real xml document i got for each page three descriptions. First is always chmod, second is always 777 and the third one can be calculated with a xml transformation. But I have to create for each page those three parameters.

Comment: I am afraid that's not clear enough.There are three pages in your example - can there be more? And what exactly determines which description a page gets?

Comment: OHey Michael, there are maximum 5 pages per xml. I need for each page one (or in real xml three) description, with the same content and with the same number as it is for page. I have checked the example once more.

Comment: I am sorry, but you're not being clear. I have edited my answer according to my best understanding of your requirements.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot! That was what I'm searching for ;)